# Template is not displaying in tab of my custom module

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, custom, tabs

I have an admin custom module in which there are three tabs present. First tab is use to collect basic informations of the module and second one is used for avanced information collection.

I want some of the content portions render with a template file and rest of the content render with the tab file itself in my second tab. Here is my second tab file

```
<?php
class Electronicsstore_News_Block_Adminhtml_News_Edit_Tab_Advance extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    public function __construct()
  {                  

        $this->setTemplate('news/calendar/calendar.phtml');//use to render calander field   
        parent::__construct();                    
  }

  protected function _prepareForm()
  {
    $news = new Varien_Data_Form();
    $this->setForm($news);
    $fieldset = $news->addFieldset('news_advance',  array('legend'=>Mage::helper('news')->__('Advanced Settings')));


   //use to add date; need to add start and final days in this module
    $fieldset->addField('news_stime', 'time', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('news')->__('Start Date'),
          'class'     => 'required-entry',
          'required'  => true,
          'name'      => 'title',
          'onclick' => "",
          'onchange' => "",
          'value'  => '12,04,15',
          'disabled' => false,
          'readonly' => false,
          'after_element_html' => '<small>Comments</small>',
          'tabindex' => 1
    ));
    $fieldset->addField('news_ltime', 'time', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('news')->__('End Date'),
          'class'     => 'required-entry',
          'required'  => true,
          'name'      => 'title',
          'onclick' => "",
          'onchange' => "",
          'value'  => '12,04,15',
          'disabled' => false,
          'readonly' => false,
          'after_element_html' => '<small>Comments</small>',
          'tabindex' => 1
    ));
}
}
```

so I want render the calendar template first and then it should followed by those time fields which I have set through the method `_prepareform()` in my second tab's content section. Currently it is not working together. I didn't get the template file output in my tab. Is it possible in magento?
Please enlighten me with good ideas. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this method:

```
public function __construct()
{                   

    $this->setTemplate('news/calendar/calendar.phtml');//use to render calander field   
    parent::__construct();                    
 }
```

to

```
protected function _construct() //only one underscore in front
{                  
    parent::_construct(); //only one underscore
    $this->setTemplate('news/calendar/calendar.phtml');//use to render calander field   

}
```

Comment: Thanks for youranswer. Unforunately it is asked one year back and I dont have that module with me. When I get time, I will try to recreate above situation and then test your code. :-)

Comment: @RKT-JoinMageStackDay2015. I'm sure it works :). It didn't work for you because the `parent::__construct()` method calls `_construct` method that sets the default template. Calling `setTemplate` after the `_construct` method does it's magic should solve your problem.

Comment: thanks. Then I will check it out the above logic flow and confirm it :-). Only one question. `_construct` is `public` or `protected` method ?

Comment: and i also read somewhere that `_construct` function do not require a `parent` call. But I cant confirm that point

Comment: right. It should be protected. I will change the answer.

Comment: okey what about my second point ? Do you have any clue ?

Comment: the parent call is not required for any method you override. It depends on what you are trying to do. But in this case I think it's better to call it. If you don't call it in this case I bet that the inputs in your tab will not appear in the center section of the page but they will be right below the tab name.